# Is it possible to set the rights of a file numerically but only to the user?

Tags: files, permissions, chmod

It is possible to use `chmod` numerically to set all the rights of a file:

```
chmod 644 file
```

Is it possible to set the rights numerically *only* to user's rights?

I work on Fedora Linux but the question is interesting in general to POSIX systems.

Comment: user means, owner of the file?

Comment: Sorry. I have no idea what the 2nd part of your question means. "Is it possible to set the rights numerically *only* to user's rights?" -- you seem to thing that **only** is important, but only **what**?

Answer (score 4):

No. As explained in `man chmod` (emphasis mine):

> chmod changes the
>          file mode bits of each given file according to mode, which can  be  **either  a  symbolic representation of changes to make, or an octal number
>          representing the bit pattern for the new mode bits**.

So, either you use the octal number and set all permissions, *or* you can use the letters and only specify what you want to have changed. But if you use the octal numbers, you need to specify all permissions.

Comment: With GNU chmod, you could do `chmod -0700,+0600` to set the file's user perms by removing everything from user and adding the ones you want, while leaving group/others unaffected.

Comment: @muru good point. That might be worth its own answer.